# Quicksand plugin. How to get one item in two different data-attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, filter, custom-data-attribute

I would like to receive one item `picture` while clicking on two different data-attributes `<li>`.

One item has got two options to select and should be visible while clicking on two different links.

There are `data-rooms` and `data-option` attributes in one list element.

My code looks like:

HTML:

```
<ul id="filterOptions">
  <li><a href="#" class="all active">Wszystkie</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="kawalerka">Kawalerka</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="2pokoje">2 pokojowe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="3pokoje">3 pokojowe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="sprzedaz">Sprzedaż</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="wynajem">Wynajem</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="ourHolder">
  <li class="item" data-id="id-1" data-rooms="3pokoje" data-option="wynajem">
    <img src="img/oferta/4.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-id="id-2" data-rooms="3pokoje">
    <img src="img/oferta/3.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-id="id-3" data-rooms="2pokoje">
    <img src="img/oferta/2.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-id="id-4" data-rooms="kawalerka">
    <img src="img/oferta/3.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-id="id-5" data-rooms="sprzedaz">
    <img src="img/oferta/4.jpg" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $filterType = $('#filterOptions li a.active').attr('class');
  var $holder = $('ul.ourHolder');
  var $data = $holder.clone();
  $('#filterOptions li a').click(function(e) {
    $('#filterOptions li a').removeClass('active');
    var $filterType = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if ($filterType == 'all') {
      var $filteredData = $data.find('li');
    } else if ($filterType == 'li[data-rooms=') {
      var $filteredData = $data.find('li[data-rooms=' + $filterType + ']');
    } else if ($filterType == 'li[data-option=') {
      var $filteredData = $data.find('li[data-option=' + $filterType + ']');
    } else {
      var $filteredData = $data.find('li[data-rooms=' + $filterType + '] + li[data-option=' + $filterType + ']');
    }
    $holder.quicksand($filteredData, {
      duration: 800,
      easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: you have a mistake in your big if/else, there is no items wich have class = "li[data-rooms=" or "li[data-option=".

Comment: sorry but I don't understand. Can you please write it more clear? I would be gratefull!

Comment: You have `var $filterType = $(this).attr('class');`, in your `$filterType` you can  only have these values : all active, kawalerka, 2pokoje, 3pokoje, sprzedaz or wynajem. And in your if/else statement you try to match this data with : all, li[data-rooms= or li[data-option=. Also in your JQuery selector you have this : `$data.find('li[data-rooms=' + $filterType + '] + li[data-option=' + $filterType + ']')`, you forget " : `$data.find('li[data-rooms="' + $filterType + '"] + li[data-option="' + $filterType + '"]')`